# Verify if a program is still running by PID? GetProcessForPID Fails

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

So I basically just want to know when a foreign application starts and closes.

Right now I'm just running a loop that checks this:

```
- (BOOL)isRunning:(int)AppPid{
    ProcessSerialNumber psn = { kNoProcess, kNoProcess };
    OSStatus err = GetProcessForPID(AppPid, &psn);
    if ( err != noErr ){
        NSLog(@"Error %d", err);
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

The issue i'm running into is that if I call this function too much (lets say 50 times in a second), it will eventually  fail and say the process isn't running, when it actually is.

This could happen once every 10 minutes, or 5 times in a row, it's unpredictable.

My question - is there another easy way via Cocoa/Objective-C to determine if a process is running (that doesn't involve a system task calling ps, as doing that 50 times/second isn't smart)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's `[NSRunningApplication runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier:]`.

If you want to know when a particular application launches and exits, there are some notifications on NSWorkspace you can listen for, specifically `NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification` and `NSWorkspaceDidTerminateApplicationNotification`.

You can then check the `NSWorkspaceApplicationKey` of the notification's `userInfo` dictionary to retrieve the `NSRunningApplication` that corresponds to the launched or terminated application, which you can match via bundle ID (or whatever) to determine if it's the application you're interested in.

Comment: I'm assuming the asker wants the scope to be other processes, not just applications.

Answer (score 1):

> My question - is there another easy way via cocoa/Objective-C to
>   determine if a process is running (that doesn't involve a system task
>   calling ps, as doing that 50 times/second isn't smart).

You could use the apple sample code ([GetBSDProcessList](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/#qa/qa2001/qa1123.html)), cache it, and check on that. That way you only get one call for the process list.